# Xcode 7 what happens when I disable bitcode for a project?

Tags: ios, xcode7, bitcode

I'm trying to understand what are the implications of disabling bitcode for a project. As far as I understand Apple intends to use it for some behind the scene optimizations for future API changes. However, a lot of the frameworks/Cocoapods that I'm using don't use bitcode, so I had to disable it. Should I try to resolve the issue rather than just disabling bitcode? What are the advantages of shipping a binary with bitcode enabled?

**What are the implications of disabling bitcode for a project with cocoapods or other 3rd party libraries?**

Answer (score 2):

Mainly Apple will not optimise it in future automatically if you have disabled it. Read below details of Apple docs.

> Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps
>   you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and
>   linked on the App Store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to
>   re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a
>   new version of your app to the store.
>
> Xcode hides symbols generated during build time by default, so they
>   are not readable by Apple. Only if you choose to include symbols when
>   uploading your app to iTunes Connect would the symbols be sent to
>   Apple. You must include symbols to receive crash reports from Apple.
>
> Note: For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. If you
>   provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle (all
>   targets in the project) need to include bitcode. For watchOS and tvOS
>   apps, bitcode is required.